# How can I figure out a new row by current row divide its last row by dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
 price = 
  price
0 111
1 222
2 333
3 444
```

I want newprice =

```
  price
0 111
1 222/111
2 333/222
3 444/333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [`df.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
In [1046]: df['new_price'] = df.price.div(df.price.shift()).fillna(df.price)

In [1047]: df
Out[1047]: 
   price   new_price
0    111  111.000000
1    222    2.000000
2    333    1.500000
3    444    1.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `shift` function from pandas, which shifts the index by desired number of periods. For example, if your variable is `price = pd.DataFrame ([111,222,333,444])`, so you will get your desired result with `price / price.shift (periods=1, fill_value=1).`